# Can't Store(Save) the QPainter Image

Tags: c++, qt, ubuntu, qt5, qpainter

I'm combining 2 QImages ("firstImage" and "secondImage") vertically with the help of QPainter. Combined image displays properly, with no error, as seen from the screen shot:

[Combined Image Displays Properly](https://ibb.co/X5S4zKm)

[First Image](https://ibb.co/7bQ1mqF)

[Second Image](https://ibb.co/fDqsWV3)

*But if I want to store the "combinedImage" by using .save, program halts and I get assert error.*

How can I store the combined image into the harddisk?

mainwindow.cpp:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QPainter>
#include <QImage>
#include <QPaintEvent>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void  MainWindow::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *)
{

    QString firstImagePath = "/home/nvidia/Desktop/TestFolder/firstImage.jpg";
    QString secondImagePath = "/home/nvidia/Desktop/TestFolder/secondImage.jpg";
    QImage firstImage(firstImagePath);
    QImage secondImage(secondImagePath);
    QImage combinedImage;
    QPainter paint(this);

    paint.begin(&combinedImage);
    paint.drawImage(0, 0, firstImage);
    paint.drawImage(0, firstImage.height()*1.1, secondImage);
    paint.end();

    bool i = firstImage.save("/home/nvidia/Desktop/TestFolder/firstImage-Copy.bmp");
    Q_ASSERT(i);

    bool j = combinedImage.save("/home/nvidia/Desktop/TestFolder/combinedImage-Copy.bmp");
    Q_ASSERT(j);
}
```

mainwindow.h:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *);

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

Here is the Qt output:

```
Starting /home/nvidia/qtprojects/build-CombinedSave-Jetson_TX2-Debug/CombinedSave...
QPainter::begin: Painter already active
ASSERT: "j" in file ../CombinedSave/mainwindow.cpp, line 39
The program has unexpectedly finished.
/home/nvidia/qtprojects/build-CombinedSave-Jetson_TX2-Debug/CombinedSave crashed
```

firstImage-Copy.bmp is stored  in the TestFolder but combinedImage-Copy.bmp is not..

Some of my system and program properties:

```
ARMv8 Processor rev 3 (v8l) × 4 ARMv8 Processor rev 0 (v8l) × 2
Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
Qt Creator 3.5.1 Based on Qt 5.5.1 (GCC 5.2.1 20151129, 64 bit)
```

Comment: A couple of quick questions: 1) Why do you `QPainter paint(this)` then `paint.begin(&combinedImage);`?  The QPainter constructor does not take a Qt-style parent, but a `QPaintDevice*`. This constructor begins painting that device.  This means that either you should `QPainter paint(&combinedImage);` and then you don't need the `begin`, or you should construct without a device: `QPainter paint;`. 2) I would construct `combinedImage` with the correct dimensions and then paint, so that `drawImage` needn't resize. (I don't whether that function does so reliably.) Have you tried that?

Comment: 1) I just copy paste some examples and do some trials. Not an expert, my code is not very intentional. So I fixed the initializer according to your and G.M.'s comments.
2) I did so, as you and G.M. stated. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the code...

```
QPainter paint(this);
paint.begin(&combinedImage);
```

The first line is essentially...

```
QPainter paint;
paint.begin(this);
```

and makes the `QPainter` active on `this` (your `MainWindow` instance).  But you then have...

```
paint.begin(&combinedImage);
```

which makes a second call to `QPainter::begin` on the already active `QPainter`.  That's probably the source of the error message...

> QPainter::begin: Painter already active

In addition, you also initialize `combinedImage` using the default `QImage` constructor...

```
QImage combinedImage;
```

At that point `combinedImage` is a null image -- it has no size or format associated with it and cannot be used as-is.

To initialise and render `combinedImage` try...

```
QImage combinedImage(std::max(firstImage.width(), secondImage.width()), /* Width */
                     firstImage.height() + secondImage.height(),        /* Height */
                     QImage::Format_ARGB32_Premultiplied);              /* Format */
{
    QPainter paint(&combinedImage);
    paint.drawImage(0, 0, firstImage);
    paint.drawImage(0, firstImage.height(), secondImage);
}
```

Comment: Note that `QPainter::begin` returns `false` if it it gets a null `QImage`, while this error can't be checked if the constructor-begin is used.  If the OP had checked the `begin` output the problem would've been solved sooner, no doubt.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful response. I did the fixing as you stated. Yes I can store the combinedImage-Copy.bmp into the harddisk properly, but main window displays nothing. If this is fixed, all will be solved

Comment: @SoajanII, the `QImage` is not associated with the `QMainWindow` in your code.  One simple option is to create a `QLabel` and visualize the `QImage` with that.  To do this, use `QLabel::setPixmap`.  You will need to use `QPixmap::fromImage`.  Finally, add the label to the `QMainWindow` with `setCentralWidget`.  Qt has excellent documentation, check it out.

Comment: @G.M. I did as you stated and this one helped too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25478186/qt-qimage-to-qpixmap-conversion-loses-color-information-for-ui  . Thanks a lot :)